# Line detection using hough line Transform openCV android

Tags: android, opencv, hough-transform

I'm trying to use hough transform to detect the four edges of a rectangle in my image. However, the result is not what I expected:

[image]

As you can see, it detected one line somewhere on the leaf instead of the four edges.

```
Mat binary_image = new Mat();

Imgproc.threshold(gray_img, binary_image, 80, 255,   Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

//line detection
Mat lines = new Mat();
Imgproc.HoughLinesP( binary_image, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, 80, 5, 5 );

for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++)
    {
        double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
        double x1 = vec[0],
                y1 = vec[1],
                x2 = vec[2],
                y2 = vec[3];
        Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point end = new Point(x2, y2);

        Core.line(mask, start, end, new Scalar(255,0,0), 1);

    }
```

Can anyone tell me what to do to make it right?

Comment: Take a look at squares.cpp in OpenCV samples. It uses polygon approximation of the contours to decide whether the shape is a square. I think a similar approach is more suitable for your case than using Hough lines.

Comment: Thx for the reply@dhanushka, but I need the length of the four edges, does it give me those info?

Comment: Of course. As I said, take a look at the example code. There you'll see it's calculating the angles. You can use those points to get the lengths.